# python page response benchmarking (headers)

Tags: python, request, web, urllib2, httplib

How can I get so-to-say *page's response time*: time between request is sent and the first header's byte comes?

PS: Here I don't want to deal with sockets - it would work, but it is too raw.

PPS: with curl in bash you can do it like this:

```
(time curl URL --head) 2>&1 | grep real | cut -c 6-
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you going:

```
from timeit import Timer
from urllib2 import urlopen

def fetch():
    page = urlopen('http://www.google.com')
    return page.info()

timer = Timer(fetch)
print timer.timeit(1)
```

Comment: Okay. Should I use HEAD request instead of GET?

Comment: If you really want only the header, instead of urllib2, you can use `HTTPConnection` from httplib.  I can update the answer if you want to see that.  httplib is a bit more low level.

Comment: Thanks, Nathan. It maybe halpful: urllib2 is also good for HEAD :)